# What is the bug in this JavaScript Snake Game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging

I used this tutorial: Snake Game HTML5 Game Programming Tutorial javascript to make a similar game.

The problem is about the movement of the snake:

The snake should move properly after pressing a arrow key but it doesn't and it moves automatically by itself.
At the same time, the food (apple) is not visible in the game.
Here is the JS Fiddle with CSS and HTML file included:

https://jsfiddle.net/L734u1y9/#&togetherjs=SeiyP5qa1m

Can somebody help me to find the error?

```
//Constants
            var COLS= 26, ROWS = 26;
//IDs
            var EMPTY = 0, SNAKE = 1, FRUIT = 2;
//Directions
            var LEFT = 0, UP = 1, RIGHT = 2, DOWN = 3;
//KeyCodes
            var KEY_LEFT = 27, KEY_UP = 38, KEY_RIGHT = 39, KEY_DOWN = 40;

            var grid= {

                width: null,
                height:null,
                _grid: null,


                init: function(d, c, r) {
                    this.width = c;
                    this.height = r;

                this._grid = [];
                for (var x = 0; x < c; x++) {
                this._grid.push([]);
                    for (var y = 0; y < r; y++){
                        this._grid[x].push(d);
                }
              }
            },

                set: function(val, x, y) {
                    this._grid[x][y] = val;

                },

                get: function (x, y) {
                    return this._grid[x][y]; 
                }
            };

            var snake= {
                direction:null,
                last: null,
                _queue: null,

                init: function (d, x, y) {
                    this.direction = d;

                    this._queue = [];
                    this.insert (x, y);

                },

                insert: function(x, y) {
                    this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y});
                    this.last = this._queue[0];

                },

                remove: function() {
                    return this._queue.pop();


                }
            };

            function setFood() {
                var empty = [];
                for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
                        if(grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
                            empty.push({x:x, y:y});
                            }
                                    }
                    }
                var randpos = empty[Math.floor(Math.random()*empty.length)];
                grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.y);

                            }

//Game Objects
            var canvas, ctx, keystate, frames;


            function main() {
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width =COLS*20;
                canvas.height = ROWS*20;
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                frames = 0;
                keystate = {};
                document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
                    keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
                });
                document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
                    delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
                });

                init();
                loop();

            }

            function init () {

                grid.init(EMPTY,COLS, ROWS);

                var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
                snake.init (UP, sp.x, sp.y);
                grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);

                setFood();

            } 

            function loop() {
                update();
                draw();

                window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);

            }

            function update() {
                frames++;

                if (keystate[KEY_LEFT] && snake.direction !== RIGHT) 
                    snake.direction = LEFT;
                if (keystate[KEY_UP] && snake.direction !== DOWN) 
                    snake.direction = UP;
                if (keystate[KEY_RIGHT] && snake.direction !== LEFT) 
                    snake.direction = RIGHT;
                if (keystate[KEY_DOWN] && snake.direction !== UP) 
                    snake.direction = DOWN;



                if (frames%5 === 0 ) {
                    var nx = snake.last.x;
                    var ny = snake.last.x;

                    switch (snake.direction) {
                        case LEFT:
                            nx--;
                            break;
                        case UP:
                            ny--;
                            break;
                        case RIGHT:
                            nx++;
                            break;
                        case DOWN:
                            ny++;
                            break;
                    }

                if (nx < 0 || nx > grid.width-1 || 
                    ny < 0 || ny > grid.height-1 ||
                    grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE

                   ) {
                    return init();
                }
                    if (grid.get(nx, ny) === FRUIT) {
                        var tail = {x:nx, y:ny}; 
                        setFood(); 
                    } else {

                    var tail = snake.remove();
                    grid.set(EMPTY, tail.x, tail.y);
                    tail.x = nx;
                    tail.y = ny;

                }

                    grid.set(SNAKE, tail.x, tail.y);

                    snake.insert(tail.x, tail.y);
            }
            }


            function draw() {
                var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
                var th = canvas.height/grid.height;

                for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
                    for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
                        switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
                            case EMPTY:
                                ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                                break;
                            case SNAKE:
                                ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
                                break;
                            case FRUIT:
                                ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
                                break;
                        }
                        ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, y*th, tw, th);
                                    }
                    }
            }
main();
```

Comment: "But apparently it needs some debugging! " -- throw a guy a bone, why don't you?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher What do u mean?! I think some misunderstanding is happening here... I did my best to find a bug but unfortunately i am so noob in this language that i can't find it! Sorry if this sentence wasn't clearly enough!

Comment: That means that you need to both explain what the code *is* doing and what you *expect* it to do.  All you said is that it doesn't work right.

Comment: Can you add please what is that is not working and what you expect? I see blinking rectangles. What's wrong with that? ;-)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher  I think the problem is about the movement of the snake... The snake should move properly after pressing a arrow key but it doesn't and it moves automatically by itself. At the same time, the food (apple) is not visible in the game!

Comment: @ib11 I think the problem is about the movement of the snake... The snake should move properly after pressing a arrow key but it doesn't and it moves automatically by itself. At the same time, the food (apple) is not visible in the game!

Comment: Update your question to put that info in... althought that is really two questions and you sort out the movement before worrying about the food.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Sure! Thx buddy!!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found *part* of your problem:

```
if (nx < 0 || nx > grid.width-1 || 
                ny < 0 || ny > grid.height-1 ||
                grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE

               ) {
               return init();
```

This constantly calls `init` over and over which restores your snake to the default position.

Removing this line and your snake stays still until movement starts.

It still pulls down and two the right -- which hints to me that you want to check the direction handling code.  Use either the debugging tools built into the browser (or console.log) to ensure those values are what you think they are.

Comment: Thank you! I recoded the whole thing and also changed the graphics! Now, I have submitted my extra ideas that i want to add to the game but i don't know how to code it... Can you help me with that?? : http://stackoverflow.com/q/37500556/4204705